# Haskell function to generate random number such that each time the number is different from previous one

Tags: haskell, random

I want a 6 digit number generated randomly. It is guaranteed that I'll never call this function more than 1000 times. The function should be able to return distinct number each time I call it.

I want to call this function like `nextRandom` without any argument. Is there any library in Haskell which would it for me? I can not maintain a seed. Haskell can use current time as `seed`.

UPDATE : Context of problem.

I am generating a graph (in dot format) and I want to make sure that all vertices have distinct labels. I can do it with attaching the time of generation as labels but I was bitten by the idea by doing so by generating random numbers.

Comment: "Therefore I can expect the function to return me distinct number each time" - wild assumption. if you just generate random numbers, there's a chance for duplicates. In fact the probability is worse than what your intuition says. Check birthday paradox.

Comment: Karoly, while what you say is true, I dislike using the word "paradox", because it isn't illogical or anything like that :P Much like saying the "Monty Hall paradox", I prefer "Monty Hall problem".

Comment: Think about the type signature of a function without any parameter and you will find that it is a value not a function

Comment: @Wes: a mathematical paradox is never illogical, just counterintuitive.

Comment: Random and "distinct number each time I call it" aren't the same at all. Did you want no repetitions at all? It sounds like you're asking for a list of numbers in random order, rather than a random number each time.

Comment: [1..1000] gives you 1000 random numbers. :)

Comment: If @augustss random list perhaps lacks a certain element of surprise :-), you could always call "shuffle" on it.

Answer (score 7):

Pure functions (like `nextRandom`, with no arguments) are like mathematical functions. On every call they produce the same results with the same arguments.

So what you're asking for it's not possible, because

- You expect random numbers.
- You expect the function has some kind of memory to know which numbers were already generated.

Just go the haskell way, and pass the seed or random generator to the function, or use a monad. If it helps, you can create the 1000 numbers in advance, and then retrieve them from a list.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a pure function that returns a distinct number each time. Its output depends on its previous invocations, not on its arguments only. But you can create a monad that carries the set of numbers generated so far, and retries generating a random number until it finds one that hasn't been generated so far. For the following example I used the [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html) package.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Random
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.IntSet (IntSet)
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS
import System.Random (getStdGen)

type RandDistinct g a = StateT IntSet (Rand g) a

evalDistinct :: RandomGen g => RandDistinct g a -> g -> a
evalDistinct k = evalRand (evalStateT k IS.empty)
```

The above type uses `StateT` to enhance a random number generator to remember the set of generated numbers so far. When we want to evaluate a computation in this monad, we start with an empty set and evaluate the inside computation with `evalRand`.

Now we can write a function that returns a distinct number each time:

```
nextDistinct :: RandomGen g => (Int,Int) -> RandDistinct g Int
nextDistinct range = loop
  where
    -- Loop until we find a number not in the set
    loop = do
        set <- get
        r <- getRandomR range
        if IS.member r set
          then loop -- repeat
          else put (IS.insert r set) >> return r
```

And test how it works:

```
main = getStdGen >>= print . evalDistinct (replicateM 50 $ nextDistinct (10, 99))
```

Note that `nextDistinct` uses a simple strategy - retry generating a new number if it already exists in the set. This works fine as long as the number of collisions is low.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to here more about the context where the function you are asking about would be used. I'm far from an expert but would something like this help you out?

```
import Control.Monad.Random

rnd :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g Int
rnd = getRandomR (100000,999999)

main = do
  putStr "\nPlease type 'nextRandom' or 'quit':\n> "
  mainLoop [] where
    mainLoop memory = do
      command <- getLine
      case command of
        "nextRandom" -> do next <- randomLoop memory
                           putStr (show next ++ "\n> ")
                           mainLoop (next:memory)
        "quit"       -> return ()
        otherwise    -> putStr "\n> "
    randomLoop memory = do  
      value <- evalRandIO rnd
      if elem value memory 
         then randomLoop memory
         else return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but if you just need a generic sampling-without-replacement routine, you can use something like [this example module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779630/better-way-of-taking-random-sample-without-replacement-from-list-in-haskell/13782206#13782206) I whipped up for another question on SO.

Just generate however many distinct six-digit numbers you need in advance, and use them wherever you want.  Ex:

```
import System.Random.MWC
import Sample

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ns <- withSystemRandom . asGenIO $ \gen -> sample [100000..999999] 10 gen
  print ns

-- [754056,765889,795475,389702,120426,740641,556446,490338,534738,213852]
```